Upload files from network computer into blob storage via Azure Synapse Notebook
I want to upload CSV / Zip / Etc... files from the company's on-premise shared drive to blob storage.
I would like to clarify if there is a way to do so.
First I need to upload files from the shared drive to blob, after ETL job via Synapse Notebook, the finished files will be transferred back to the shared drive.
The websites that I found weren't helpful.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python?tabs=managed-identity%2Croles-azure-portal%2Csign-in-azure-cli&pivots=blob-storage-quickstart-template
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-upload
Is there a PySpark code that allows this? this is what I found
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Configuration
storage_account_name = "<your_storage_account_name>"
storage_account_key = "<your_storage_account_key>"
container_name = "<your_container_name>"
file_path = "<path_to_your_file.csv>"
blob_name = "<your_blob_name.csv>"

# Create a Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("Shared to Blob Transfer") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Read the CSV file from NFS
df = spark.read.csv(file_path, header=True, inferSchema=True)

# Define the output path in Blob Storage
output_path = f"wasbs://{container_name}@{storage_account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/{blob_name}"

# Write the DataFrame to Blob Storage
df.write.csv(output_path, header=True, mode="overwrite")

print(f"Uploaded {file_path} to {container_name}/{blob_name} in Azure Blob Storage.")

